# Filtering Stream object in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, dom-events, streaming

It seems to me that an elegant way to process certain kinds of data in Node.js would be to chain processing objects, like UNIX pipes.

For example, grep:

```
function Grep(pattern) {
    ...
}
util.inherits(Grep, stream.Stream);

Grep.prototype.???? = ???????  // What goes here?

grep = new Grep(/foo/);

process.stdin.pipe(grep);
myStream.pipe(process.stdout);
```

However it's not at all clear to me how the various Stream methods need to be overridden in order for this to work.

How can I create a Stream object that simply copies from its input to its output? Presumably with that answered, more sophisticated filtering streams become trivial.

**Update:** it feels as if the following should work (expressed in CoffeeScript, so I don't fill this box with JS syntax!):

```
class Forwarder extends stream.Stream
    write: (chunk, encoding) ->
        @emit 'data', chunk
    end: (chunk, encoding) =>
        if chunk?
            @emit 'data', chunk
        @emit 'end'

fwd = new Forwarder()
fwd.pipe(process.stdout);
process.stdin.pipe(fwd);
process.stdin.resume();
```

However catting something to this script doesn't output anything. Calling `fwd.write()` explicitly in the script does cause output on `stdout`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are so very close.

Because you are using the very low-level stream class, you need to set the stream writable property to make it a writable stream. If you were reading from the stream, you'd need to set the readable property. Also the end event doesn't have any arguments.

```
class Forwarder extends stream.Stream
  constructor: ->
    @writable = true
  write: (chunk, encoding) ->
    @emit 'data', chunk
  end: ->
    @emit 'end'

fwd = new Forwarder()
fwd.pipe(process.stdout);
process.stdin.pipe(fwd);
process.stdin.resume();
```

#### Update

The answer above applied to V1 streams in Node <= 0.8. If you are using > 0.8, Node has added more specific classes that are designed to be extended, so you would use something more like this:

```
class Forwarder extends stream.Transform
    _transform: (chunk, encoding, callback) ->
      this.push(chunk);
      callback();
```

Processing `chunk` and pushing the pieces you actually want.

Comment: Bingo! I had tried using '@writable: true' as a static member; that doesn't work. But putting it in the constructor does.

Comment: Augh!  I spent quite a while debugging this because I put 'writeable' instead of 'writable'.  Be sure you get the word correct!

Comment: @BT True enough, I probably just never considered it at the time since the question only used `write` and `end, though `pause` on V1 streams was a bit weird. The V2 stream version in my update should work properly anyway, so I'm not sure it's worth worrying about now.

Answer (score 3):

Although the answer that exists is nice, it still requires a bit of digging around on behalf of those looking for answers.

The following code completes the example the OP gave, using the Node 0.10 stream API.

```js
var stream = require('stream')
var util = require('util')

function Grep(pattern) {
  stream.Transform.call(this)

  this.pattern = pattern
}

util.inherits(Grep, stream.Transform)

Grep.prototype._transform = function(chunk, encoding, callback) {
  var string = chunk.toString()

  if (string.match(this.pattern)) {
    this.push(chunk)
  }

  callback()
}

var grep = new Grep(/foo/)
process.stdin.pipe(grep)
grep.pipe(process.stdout)
```

Comment: Looks like this searches for the given pattern on every chunk separately. If one chunk ends in "fo" and the next starts with "o", it would have missed it.