# custom stream object? (nodejs)

Tags: node.js

Is it possible to extend / initialize the require('stream').Stream; object ? I would like to be able to create a stream object that i can push data to and have all the listeners notified when new data arrive.

I tried the following:

```
var stream = require('stream');
var test = new stream.Stream();
test.write(new Buffer('mads'));
```

But i get the following error:

```
TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'write'
    at repl:1:6
    at Interface.<anonymous> (repl.js:168:22)
    at Interface.emit (events.js:67:17)
    at Interface._onLine (readline.js:153:10)
    at Interface._line (readline.js:408:8)
    at Interface._ttyWrite (readline.js:585:14)
    at ReadStream.<anonymous> (readline.js:73:12)
    at ReadStream.emit (events.js:88:20)
    at ReadStream._emitKey (tty_posix.js:306:10)
    at ReadStream.onData (tty_posix.js:69:12)
    at ReadStream.emit (events.js:67:17)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to create those methods yourself and also set the `writable` property to true, and don't forget to `emit` the events in those methods you override as well so that you can use it as a regular event emitter. Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6944319/filtering-stream-object-in-node-js) for more information.

Comment: I want to use such custom stream as `stdout` and `stderr` for a child_process. But its saying `Incorrect value for stdio stream: [object Object]`. What could be wrong here?

Comment: @Салман same problem here. Have you found solution?

Comment: I actually wanted to redirect output of a `child_process` to a file, but it should be decided by the child itself, (unlike the parent opens an fd and give pass it while `spawn`ing). I couldn't figure it out, so had to open the fd in parent only.

Answer (score 13):

For anyone who stumbles on this question today (node v0.10.x), this can be easily achieved using the [PassThrough](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_passthrough) stream introduced with streams2.

```
var stream = require('stream');
var test = stream.PassThrough();
test.write('mads');
test.end();
```